# Scrape dynamic site using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, salesforce, puppeteer, cheerio

I am trying to builder a simple scraper that would scrape the [Trailblazer Profile](https://trailblazer.me/id/akganesa) site.
I want to get the number of badges and points of the user.

So I am using cheerio and puppeteer to accomplish this.

here is my code -->

```
 .get("/:profile", (req,res,next) => {

  const url = "https://trailblazer.me/id/hverma99";

  async function getPage(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    const html = await page.content(); // serialized HTML of page DOM.
    await browser.close();
    return html;
  }

  const html = getPage(url);
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  const span = $('.tds-tally__count.tds-tally__count_success');
  console.log(span.text());

});
```

the profile parameter is not being used as of right now as I am just testing this.

> Problem :
>   Whenever I run this code I do not get anything printed on the console and if i try without puppeteer then I only get the html without any data.
>   My expected result is the number of badges and points.

Let me know what is wrong with this code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is correct. All you have to do is `await` your `getPage` call as it is async. try this

```
.get("/:profile", async (req,res,next) => {

  const url = "https://trailblazer.me/id/hverma99";

  async function getPage(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    const html = await page.content(); // serialized HTML of page DOM.
    await browser.close();
    return html;
  }

  const html = await getPage(url);
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  const span = $('.tds-tally__count.tds-tally__count_success');
  console.log(span.text());

});
```

Also need to put `async` like this - `async (req,res,next)`